# Every 202,500 years, Earth wanders in a new direction; does it affect climate?

Tags: climate-change, climate, earth-observation, sun, milankovitch-cycles

I refer to this article on nytimes.com: [Every 202,500 Years, Earth Wanders in a New Direction](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17142736)

TLDR: Scientists believe the earth's orbit oscillates between circular
and more elliptical due to the gravitational pull from Jupiter (big)
and Venus (close). It takes 405k years to complete a cycle.

The big question: could this affect climate-change? Could it make colder winters, hotter summers or just more extreme weathers? Changing Gulf stream?

Comment: It's important to note that these changes, while real, take place gradually and continuously, over many thousands of years.

Answer (score 9):

Milankovitch cycles do affect climate on Earth. There are several cycles.

> "Variations in [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity), [axial tilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt), and [precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession) of the Earth's
>   orbit resulted in cyclical variation in the solar radiation reaching
>   the Earth, and that this orbital forcing strongly influenced climatic
>   patterns on Earth."
>   source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles)

Scientists of Pleistocene's climate evolution strongly correlate Milankovitch cycles with glacial/interglacial periods, affecting the Gulf Stream Current.
Other factors of Earth's internal system, such as volcanic events do affect climate, but changes in the magnitude of solar radiation are a well known climatic variability generator.